# Stored (persistent) serializable objects can't be readed properly in a newer market version of my app

Tags: android, serialization, inputstream, objectinputstream

I have a android app wich store persistent serializable object containin 4 arraylists of strings. This object is stored on the internal memory, and it is recovered eachtime the app starts. It works fine.... the problem is that when i launch a newwer version of the app on the market and the users download and install the newer version, the stored object is not recovered properly, the four arraylists of the object are recovered empty. Then, the users lost their previous version of the app stored data. This is a huge problem that i must solve.

This is my serializable object:

```
public class SaveState implements Serializable{
    public ArrayList <String> fNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList <String> fNames = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    public ArrayList <String> favNumbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList <String> favNames= new ArrayList<String>();
    public static SaveState instance=new SaveState();
}
```

And these are the methods i use to store and recover this persistent object:

```
public static void saveData(Context context){
        ObjectOutput out;
        try {           
            File directory = context.getDir(STORE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //primero comprobamos si existe el directorio, y si no, lo creamos.
            File outFile = new File(directory, "appSaveState.data");
            System.out.println("########## SAVING INTO: "+outFile.getAbsolutePath());
            out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile)); 
            out.writeObject(SaveState.instance);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public static void loadData(Context context){
        ObjectInput in;
        try {
            File directory = context.getDir(STORE_DIRECTORY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //primero comprobamos si existe el directorio, y si no, lo creamos.
            File inFile = new File(directory, "appSaveState.data"); 
            System.out.println("########## LOADING FROM: "+inFile.getAbsolutePath());
            in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(inFile)); //intentamos cargar el fichero     
            SaveState.instance=(SaveState) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```

Remember that this code works fine if the version of the app is not updated.

What is wrong? What should i do to make this data persistent between diferent android market versions of my app?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert on the matter, but I believe serialization can be inconsistent in certain situations. You'll have stable results if you use something reliable like JSON or XML. I'm sorry that this won't help with your current problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would serialize the data myself and not rely on the Java object serialization.

Instead of writing the objects to an ObjectOutputStream you can convert your data into an XML document and write that file to storage (I see it is all Strings anyway, so shouldn't be difficult). Then you can read and write the data using classes available to handle XML. In this case you know that the data you have on disk can always be read by whatever version of your program you've got.

The problem with Java serialization is that it relies heavily on reflection and if the underlying class' implementation changes you are hosed.

Comment: i know there are other ways to store data, but i want to learn how to solve the problem with this way, thanks bytheway